# Load Tensor From Buffer using PyTorch and Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pytorch, torch

Given a file io binary buffer I would like to construct a tensor from the raw bytes, in some shape and in some offset without loading it into `numpy`, but instead directly into `torch` and `tensorflow`.

In `numpy`, my method would be:

```py
def unpack_numpy(s: struct.Struct, shape: Tuple, buffer: bytes, read_offset: int):
   return np.ndarray(shape, s.format, buffer, read_offset)
```

Is there a way to implement this for `pytorch`?

```py
def unpack_torch(s: struct.Struct, shape: Tuple, buffer: bytes, read_offset: int):
   # ???
```

There exists `torch.as_tensor`, but it can't set the shape, or the read offset from the buffer.

Same question for `tensorflow` - Is there a way to implement this for `tensorflow`?

```py
def unpack_tensorflow(s: struct.Struct, shape: Tuple, buffer: bytes, read_offset: int):
   # ???
```

There exists `tf.io.decode_raw`, but it can't set the shape, or the read offset.